# Entity Framework Code First - Model Change with two versions of code (pre model change and post model change)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have two environments (A and B) that share the same backing database, this database uses the ASP.Net Identity 2.0 framework, thus using EF underneath.  The two environments may be running separate versions of the code at any time -- with the B version usually running the older code (i.e. I would deploy to A first and test any change, before deploying to B).

When I add a new property to a model, and utilize the EF migrations the new column is added to the underlying database.  This code will be deployed to A first, and will modify the same database that B is using.  B then throws an exception about an unknown property (column) being found in the database table.

Is there a way I can handle this?  Basically I would like the code that doesn't know about the new column to 'ignore' it -- or set it to a default value.

Comment: So your environments both point to the same database?

Comment: Yes, we basically use A as a staging environment for B.

Comment: You realise how dangerous that is right?

Comment: Yes -- it's just the current system we have in place and have to work with.

Comment: You should really just spin up a new database in your SQL Server for your B environment then. That shouldn't take more than a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent entity framework from checking model matches the database by setting a null initialiser in your context constructor:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext() : base("YourContextConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
    }

    //Rest of context here

}
```

It may also work if you disable it in the web.config for B only:

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
        <context type="YourNamespace.YourContext, YourAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" />
    </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Would that mean my A environment would require the initializer to be my migration enabled initializer, and let B utilize the null initializer?  I.e. A would always do the migrations in preparation for B to just assume it is in the valid state?

Comment: Hope it works, but it doesn't solve the problem you will eventually get which is the danger of having the same database for A and B. Also, what happens if you need to remove a column or change a data type?